# I am not getting the output. What changes should be made to get correct output? I need to get file name as output

Tags: php

I am not getting the output. What changes should be made to get correct output?

Actually I was trying to store image in folder using Ajax. For testing I tried this code. I need to get file name as output. I have tried this:

```
<?php
$data = pinkyvista.jpg;
echo $_FILES[$data]['name'];
?>
```

Comment: I think: echo $data; will give you the name..

Comment: This code gives you a syntax error, and nothing else. Read the manual for [uploading images](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) first.

Comment: but can u please tell me how to operate image using $_FILES property @Dieter

Comment: can we use $_Files without using <form_field_name>....??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are uploading the file using Ajax, and the script you posted is in the php part of file upload,

```
$_FILES["<form_field_name>"]["name"]
```

is what you need to print the file name, where **form_field_name** is the name of file field in the upload form.

Comment: but can we operate $_FILES without using <form_field_name> @srijith Vijayamohan